# JAXB Out of order unmarshalling references @XmlID and @XmlIDREF

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following xml:

Company.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<company>
    <employeeList>
        <employee name="Jane Doe" id="A">
        </employee>
        <employee name="John Smith" id="B">
        </employee>
        <employee name="Anne Jones" id="C">
        </employee>
    </employeeList>
</company>
```

Department.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<departmentList>
    <departmentList>
        <department name="Dev" id="1">
            <employee>A</employee>
            <employee>B</employee>
        </department>
        <department name="Sales" id="2">
            <employee>C</employee>
        </department>
    </departmentList>
</departmentList>
```

The class Department.java has an employee list

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Department {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name="employee")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EmpAdapter.class)
    public List<Employee> employeeList; 

    public Department(){
        employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }
```

and the employee.java class has an id attribute with the @XmlId tag.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

        @XmlAttribute
        @XmlID
        private String id;
```

I know how to get the employee objects to be pointed at from the department object using an adapter. However that is if the Company.xml file is unmarshalled first because it has the employee details in it.

So what I want is to be able to unmarshall the Department.xml first and have it create some sort of placeholder so that once the Company.xml has been unmarshalled the employeeList in the department object is filled in.

**EDIT**

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**: As suggested by @laune I can use the adapter to create Employee objects as a placeholder, and then once the employee list is unmarshalled fill in these details in the employee objects under the department class

**WHAT I NEED:**
But this way I have to always handle each of the cases individually through code and new methods. Main problem is I cannot predict the order in which the unmarshalling will happen. Is there a way to have JAXB unmarshall without worrying about dependencies and ordering of creating objects? Maybe using schemas?

Comment: "Cannot predict the order in which the unmarshalling will happen": Then, make it predictable. Data can be stored in thing called file system or memory, and unmarshalled later. - To create references to objects (as in the `List<Employee>`) you need to have the objects. JAXB deals with *coherent* data sets, not whimsically arranged files.

Comment: We are considering switching from JiBX to JAXB, and want to see if the special cases we have can be implemented in JAXB. The current way works, so we want to keep intrusions to a minimum and don't want to be creating lots of new data. This is a simplified version of the question, hence why I can't just "make it predictable".

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the EmpAdapter to return a placeholder Employee object created from an (additional) constructor

```
public Employee( String id ){
    this.id = id;
}
```

Also, the EmpAdapter should maintain a `Map<String,Employee>` mapping ids to employees.

After you have unmarshalled the employees into a flat list, iterate the list and fill the fields of the placeholder (located via the map) from the list element.

Things would be much easier if employee data contains the deparment id.

Comment: Yes this would work, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I edited my question to make it clearer. Really appreciate it if you could take a look. Also why do you say it would be easier if the employee contains department id? Is it because I can just use the afterUnmarshal like shown [here](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html)

Comment: Evident: if the employees "know" their department they can be inserted into the departents' lists using trivial code.